# iOS 9: UIScrollView is broken again?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, ios9

I noticed that the `UIScrollView` might be broken again. I'm using `OS X 10.11.1` and `Xcode 7 (from AppStore)` or `Xcode 7.1 beta`. The `contentOffset` property is not at the `origin` of the `UIScrollView` after AutoLayout is done its work.

Can someone confirm this issue?

However, I managed to workaround, but this is not how it supposed to be:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.scrollView.frame.origin.y)
    /* if you need a different position, I suggest to safe the 
       contentOffset inside viewWillLayoutSubviews and calculate the offset here */
}
```

Here is how to reproduce the issue:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    private let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    private let containerView = UIView()

    override func loadView() {

        self.view = UIView()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.greenColor().CGColor
        self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = false

        self.scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)

        self.scrollView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).active = true
        self.scrollView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor).active = true
        self.scrollView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.view.widthAnchor).active = true

        self.containerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        self.containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        self.scrollView.addSubview(self.containerView)

        self.containerView.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.widthAnchor).active = true
        self.containerView.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.heightAnchor).active = true
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        print("content offset: \(self.scrollView.contentOffset)")
        print("origin: \(self.scrollView.frame.origin)")
        print("they to not match visually :( <-- BROKEN !!!")
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    }

    override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {

        return false
    }
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** Reported and also filled the radar: [22770934](https://openradar.appspot.com/22770934)

**UPDATE2:** Issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution with the help of the view debugger.

Add this missing constraints and everything will be fine:

```
self.containerView.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.topAnchor).active = true
self.containerView.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.leftAnchor).active = true
self.containerView.rightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.rightAnchor).active = true
self.containerView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.scrollView.bottomAnchor).active = true

// actually the debugger showed two different constraints, but this had no effect on the functionality, correct me here if I am wrong
// trailing and button constraints where like this:

// self.scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.trailingAnchor).active = true
// self.scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.containerView.bottomAnchor).active = true
```